# Why in a fixed array (with free spaces), Insert(rand) has a time complexity O(n)?

Tags: arrays, runtime, computer-science

I am a complete beginner, going through the course 'Udemy - Computer Science 101 Master the Theory Behind Programming'. I was stuck in finding the reason for the above statement.

Comment: Would it be possible to put a bit more of an explanation in the question? There are multiple ways that question can be interpreted, and a good answer requires knowing what exactly is meant by "insert(rand)".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A fully accurate answer probably requires a more detailed question.

I interpret this as "insert an item at a random index in an array (that has spare space)".

To insert an element in an array at any position other than "the last" requires copying all elements after the index you're inserting at.

This will, on average, require moving `n/2` elements one index later in the array.

With some charitable assumptions, moving one element is O(1), so moving n/2 elements is O(n/2), which can be simplified to O(n).

Comment: In your answer, can you please explain the statement "This will, on average, require moving n/2 elements one index later in the array."

Comment: @AniketChanda If you pick a random element between 0 and N-1, you can't say much about it, but if you pick many, their average will tend towards N/2. As you will need to move all elements after the picked index, you will (on average) need to move half of the objects.